# how to fix wine not being able to install vcrun2019 with this error: "not supported on this system"?

Tags: wine

trying to run: `winetricks vcrun2019`

on wine(s):
"wine4.0.4stable-focal"
"wine5.0.1stable-focal"
"wine5.0.2stable-focal"
"wine5.0.3stable-focal"
"wine5.21staging-focal"(the recommended at https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17444)
"wine6.0.1stable-focal-1"
"wine6.17staging-focal-2"

I always get the below error even if I try manually on the command line `wine64 vc_redist.x64.exe`

```
0024:err:process:exec_process L"C:\\vc_redist.x64.exe" not supported on this system

wine: Bad EXE format for Y:\vcrun2019\vc_redist.x64.exe #with wine 4.0.4

Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file. # wine 6.17
```

So this is a wine message, not a winetricks message.

ubuntu 20.04

Other 64bits things can run on it. And trying to install the 64 bits exe will fail!?

PS.: got versions from https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ 7z l vc_redist.x64.exe  |grep "CPU ="
CPU = x86
```

https://superuser.com/a/981980/157532

there is no fix, it is a 32 bits installer for a 64 bits thing..., and til now I am unable to run 32bits windows apps on wine on ubuntu20.04.

the contents can be extracted with `7z x ...` on the 32bits installer, but now I need to know what to do with that concerning registry stuff... Btw, `7z x` can also be used with .msi files!

I extracted another 64bits application from the weird 32bits installer, and the application is running fine!

And to extract vc_redist.x64.exe usable contents, you have to:

```
mkdir tmp
cabextract -d tmp vc_redist.x64.exe
cd tmp
cabextract *
```

Comment: You have to try  `winecfg` and set newer version of Windows. Or dig into https://www.winehq.org and ask there.

Comment: Wine 6.0 up will open winecfg correctly but wont open explorer (it complaints about missing IExplorerBrowser). I think ubuntu builds at wine repo are not being tested, they are just automatic? But Im still unable to install anything .exe that has 64bits applications because they come in a 32bits .exe file! that is just incredible (to not say worse). I still have 18.04, so I can test/install on it, and may be I can copy the 64bits application to 20.04 and it may work.